# How can I delete a job using Job DSL plugin(script) in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am very new to Jenkins and Job DSL plugin. After a little research, I found how to create a job using DSL and now I am trying to delete a job using DSL.
I know to disable a job using this following code:

```
//create new job
//freeStyleJob("MyJob1", closure = null);

job("MyJob1"){
  disabled(true);
}
```

It is working perfectly fine. But, I couldn't find any method to delete another job in jenkins.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each instance of the Job Dsl plugin tracks what jobs (and views) it creates. When it is run again, you can configure what it does to jobs (and views) that were present the previous time this instance was run, but are not present this time.

Let's a assume you have two files you use to create jobs.

`seed_jobdsl.groovy`:

```
job('seed_all') {
  steps {
    dsl {
      external('*_jobdsl.groovy')  
      // default behavior
      // removeAction('IGNORE')      
    }
  }
}
```

`test_jobdsl.groovy`:

```
job('test_stuff') {
  steps {
    shell('echo "I live!")
  }
}
```

This will leave jobs created by `seed_all` unchanged even if they are not present in the list of job created the next time seed is run.

To get jobs to be deleted, change your seed job code:

`seed_jobdsl.groovy`:

```
job('seed_all') {
  steps {
    dsl {
      external('*_jobdsl.groovy')  
      removeAction('DELETE')      
    }
  }
}
```

Now, run `seed_all` job to apply your change (`seed_all` overwrites its own configuration when run). Then make the following change:

`test_jobdsl.groovy`:

```
job('test_other') {
  steps {
    shell('echo "The job is dead, long live the new job!"')
  }
}
```

Run `seed_all` again.  You notice `test_stuff` will be deleted and `test_other` will be created.  If you remove `test_jobdsl.groovy` and then run `seed_all`, `test_other` will be deleted.

Answer (score 10):

To delete a job, you have to set the "Action for removed jobs" option to "Delete" in the "Process Job DSLs" build step configuration. Then remove the job from your script and run the seed job.