# removing jenkins job as using jenkins job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using jenkins job dsl to create pipelineJob, I do not know how to delete those jobs through the same plugin.

I wondered around in the code base, and I think it is not doable.

I thought of using the rest api to make a call to the api to delete a job, can anyone give me any lead on how to do that in groovy or extending a Java class.

Basically it would be:

- read the jobs name in the job.groovy file
- make the call to the rest api (jenkins_base_url+/job+/doDelete)

Huuuge THANKS

Comment: You can find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784488/how-can-i-delete-a-job-using-job-dsl-pluginscript-in-jenkins

Comment: I have a hard time getting that discussion.
What I would like to do is deleting all the jobs described in a file.

I have a file pipelines.groovy:
```
pipelineJob("example-1") {}
pipelineJob("example-2") {}
```

I would like to run a command from cli to delete all pipelineJobs in pipelines.groovy

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the scripts from [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218639328-How-to-delete-multiple-jobs-) and [here](https://gist.github.com/nextrevision/d11b2df4e8b229c6855b), but they look promising.

```
import jenkins.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /my_regex_here/
}

matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println job.name
    //job.delete();
}
```

If your jobs do not share a common pattern in the name and you cannot use Regex, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729302/how-to-read-a-file-in-groovy-into-a-string) and [here](https://code-maven.com/groovy-files) are some resources for reading files with groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to meet my needs I had to make an api call.

It looks like this:

```
RestApiJobManagement jm = new RestApiJobManagement(baseUrl)
HttpResponseDecorator resp = jm.restClient.get(path: 'crumbIssuer/api/xml')   
    if (resp.status == 200) {                                                     
        restClient.headers[resp.data.crumbRequestField] = resp.data.crumb         
    }                                                                             
resp = jm.restClient.post(
    path: '/job/${job.jobName}/doDelete',
    requestContentType: 'charset=UTF-8'
)
println "status ${resp.status}"
```

***The only issue is that I am unable to read through a jenkinsjobdsl.groovy file and get all job names to fill ${job.jobName}***